# C# Speech Recognition - Store user speech input to string

Tags: c#, speech

So, what I am trying to achieve is that when the SpeechSynthesizer asks "What should I call you?" and the user says "Bob", to store "Bob" in a string variable called myName as shown and reply with ("Hello" + myName).  Now, I have a list of words in a .txt file which the SpeechSynthesizer understands and "Bob" in that list.  I have a log of user speech input and I can see that it is registering it but not executing the if statement.

I do not fully understand this library and tried doing some research but cannot find anything specific to my question.

Big thing here, is the fact that i need to store it in a variable as this will solve other problems i am having.  This is more of a example problem.

Thanks in advance.

```
private void sRecognize_SpeechRecognized(object sender, SpeechRecognizedEventArgs e)
    {

        if (e.Result.Text == "listen")
        {
            listenMode = true; //resume listening
            sSynth.Speak("listening mode initializing.  Listening now");                              
        }

        if (listenMode == true)
        {
            switch (e.Result.Text)
            {                                     
                case "setup":
                    sSynth.Speak("setup initialized");
                    sSynth.Speak("what should i call you?");
                    if (e.Result.Text == "bob")
                    {
                        myName = e.Result.Text;
                        sSynth.Speak("hello " + myName);
                        break;
                    }
                    else
                        break;


                default:
                    answer.Text = answer.Text + " " + e.Result.Text.ToString();
                    break;
            }


        }
    }
```

I could so something like this (But this is not what I need).

```
case "Bob":
     sSynth.Speak("Hello Bob");
break;
```

Comment: Why do you think that `e.Result.Text` will be changed in the same event handler? I suppose `sSynth.Speak("hello " + myName);` always tells you "hello setup", correct?

Comment: Yes... still unsure on how to go about it.  My experience working with this is limited.  Have you got a suggestion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dont' think that event value is changed on fly. 
So for each portion of a recognized data new event will be raised.

I would suggest to have a parameter type / name (it is better if it would be a enum) as a variable and check that value in the handler, based on the value perform your action.

```
private string _parameter = string.Empty;

private void sRecognize_SpeechRecognized(object sender, SpeechRecognizedEventArgs e)
{
    switch(_parameter)
    {
        case string.Empty: 
        {
            switch (e.Result.Text)
            {                                     
                case "setup": _parameter = "Name"; ...
            }
            break;
        }
        case "Name" : 
        { 
            sSynth.Speak("hello " + myName); 
            _parameter = "Age";
        }
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: read also about [command pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern#C.23) looks like better for your case